# Why does Assign Material do nothing?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Following a tutorial, I created a black Material and selected Faces in edit mode and hit 'Assign'. Nothing happens, however. What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Change your viewport to rendered mode (it's the farthest right of the four little circles at the top right of the viewport window.)

Comment: This solves it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in solid mode. Materials are only displayed in rendered mode.

If you want to see a color for a material in solid mode use the viewport settings for the material.

[image]